# How can I load external dependencies using ki (Kotlin Interactive Shell)?

Tags: shell, kotlin, dependency-management

I am using using Ki ([Kotlin Language Interactive Shell](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-interactive-shell)) to run Kotlin interactively on the shell, and I came across the need to load a 3rd-party library so I can script something quick. For example, let's say I want to use [turtle](https://github.com/lordcodes/turtle) to run a simple `ls` command:

```kotlin
shellRun("ls")
```

How can I set my ki shell in a way that turtle becomes available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use the `:dependsOn` command:

```bash
[0] :dependsOn com.lordcodes.turtle:turtle:0.8.0
[1] com.lordcodes.turtle.shellRun("ls")
```

Ki allows you to download dependencies in runtime using Maven coordinates.

You can see the source code here: [`org.jetbrains.kotlinx.ki.shell.plugins.DependsOnCommand`](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-interactive-shell/blob/main/ki-shell/src/main/kotlin/org/jetbrains/kotlinx/ki/shell/plugins/DependenciesPlugin.kt#L25)

Comment: See also the section "Loading external dependencies" here: https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2021/04/ki-the-next-interactive-shell-for-kotlin/